# Deligne's letter to Soulé from 1985

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, motives

There is a famous letter of Deligne to C. Soulé in which, apparently, Deligne first formulated the conjecture on the existence of an abelian category of mixed motives, extending Grothendieck's pure motives.  For example it is mentioned in the first sentence of [Levine - Mixed motives](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/K-theory/handbook/1-429-522.pdf).

The letter seems extremely important but I could not find it online.  Is it publicly available?

Comment: I am a little concerned about having anonymous people hunting on a public forum for what would appear to be private correspondences of living people.   It seems like a morally dubious thing to be encouraging.

Comment: Deligne shares many of his letters on his website https://www.ias.edu/math/people/faculty/deligne.  If you think this one should be publicly available as well, you should contact him.

Comment: @RyanBudney Sorry about the username, I just needed to fill something into the blank. Obviously the letter is not completely private since it is widely distributed and cited by many people, so as I wrote in my question I am just asking if it is **publicly** available

Comment: Thanks @AndyPutman. I would prefer to make sure it is not already publicly available somewhere before bothering Professor Deligne. I know from asking him a similar request before that he maintains a huge collection of all his correspondence and it may be difficult and time-consuming for him to find the letter.

Comment: Dear DeligneLetterHunter: Yes, you needed to fill something into the blank. How about your name? I think @RyanBudney's point was that you could use your own name as many of us do. If you feel that you don't want to associate your own identity with this question then perhaps you should not ask it.

Comment: @SándorKovács I don't buy it. Here are three similar questions by anonymous posters: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372518/delignes-letter-to-bhargava-from-march-2004 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336825/deligne-s-letter-to-kazhdan-on-ell-adic-fourier-transform https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249979/delignes-letter-to-millson The problem here is apparently that I used the word "hunter" in my name, which was a joke that I didn't put enough thought into.

Comment: Why not ask Soulé directly?

Comment: @DeligneLetterHunter (cc: @RyanBudney): what is it that "you don't buy"? (I doubt that anyone worries about the word "hunter"). Just because there are others who post anonymously that does not mean that it is a good thing. My comment applies to those posters as well. I think there is no question that if everyone posted under their real name, then that would lead to a healthier environment. As it is, you know who I am, but I don't know who you are. That creates an unbalanced situation. I really don't see any reason why you feel the need to hide your identity.

Comment: Has anyone since managed to obtain a copy? I have since emailed Deligne and asked him to put it on his list of letters, but have not heard back.